# Distributing rows amongst partitions in a Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Expectation: I would expect that, when I partition a given dataframe, the rows will be roughly evenly distributed into each partition. I would then expect that, when I write the dataframe to csv, the resulting n csvs (in this case, 10), would similarly be of roughly equal length.

Reality: When I run the below code, I find that instead of a somewhat even distribution of rows, all rows are in `export_results-0.csv` and the remaining 9 csvs are empty.

Question: Are there additional configurations that I need to set to ensure that rows are distributed amongst all the partitions?

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

client = Client('tcp://10.0.0.60:8786')

df = pd.DataFrame({'geom': np.random.random(1000)}, index=np.arange(1000))
sd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)

tall = dd.merge(sd.assign(key=0), sd.assign(key=0), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
tall.to_csv('export_results-*.csv').compute()
```

About the above code: In the below code, I create a 1000 row dataframe and merge it with itself in order to create a 1000000 row long dataframe (the goal is to eventually generate a thin and tall table that holds the distance from any one to any other geometry from a list of 100k+).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it's noted in the dataframe performance section of the Dask docs that joins between two Dask dataframes can be very expensive.

By joining a Dask dataframe to a Pandas dataframe, I seem to be able to preserve partitioning. Here's an example modification to the above code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'geom': np.random.random(200) }, index=np.arange(200))
sd1 = dd.from_pandas(df1.copy(), npartitions=5).assign(key=0)

tall = dd.merge(sd1, df1.assign(key=0), on='key', npartitions=10).drop('key', axis=1)
tall.to_csv('exported_csvs/res-*.csv')
```

Now, this achieves the goal of maintaining partitions. That said, I would still be interested in understanding why partitions seemingly can't be preserved when merging two Dask dataframes.